# Projection topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(\prod_{i\in \mathcal{I}}X_{i},\tau)$ a topological space with some topology $\tau$. Consider the map $\pi_{i}:\prod_{i\in\mathcal{I}}X_{i}\longrightarrow X_{i}$. Can we consider a topology $\tau_{i}$ for the space $X_{i}$ induced by the topology $\tau$ and the projection? Or in other word, can we construct that $\tau_{i}$?

Comment: Whatever the opens are in your original space, what is wrong with taking their images under $\pi_i$ to be the opens in $X_i$?

Comment: You have to explain in *what sense* $\tau_i$ should be induced by $\tau$ and $p_i$. In the present status $\tau_i$ could be anything from the discrete to the trivial topology.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be somewhat careful with your indices. Let $X:= \prod_{i\in I}X_i$ and

$$\pi_j\colon X \mapsto X_j,\ \text{for}\ j\in I$$

You can always induce the *final topology* $\tau_j$ on $X_j$ via

$$\tau_j = \{U\subset X_j \mid \pi^{-1}(U) \in \tau\}$$

this is the coarsest topology on $X_j$ for which $\pi$ is continuous.